# Connecting Arduino to Firebase using GPRS

Tags: javascript, firebase, arduino, gprs

I'm doing a project which I want to send sensor's data to Firebase database. This connection must be via GPRS. To set or to push any data to Firebase database, it should be done using javascript and HTML, but the Arduino can't use javascript directly. Is there any way to make the connection?
I have a website. Would it be helpful to do the connection?
I will be really thankful if someone gave me a simple steps to follow.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "To set or to push any data to Firebase database, it should be done using javascript" why?

Comment: It is the only way I found to declare the database link, name... etc.

Comment: See this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start#section-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could request web site links ( http request) from the arduino.And in this request you can pass details to the database.This is how the data is stored to the database from Arduino.

I am bit back about firebase database.

But let me tell what we did for storing data to a normal database.We made a PHP script such that if its link is requested with data ,it would store the data to the database.Then we made Arduino code in such a way as to request that link each time with the corresponding value to be stored.So if you can do PHP scripting for firebase data entry then its easier ( just request that link from Arduino).I think PHP insertion to firebase database is available.

You can also pass data to a website too using the above method ( simple modification in url would do that ,pass data to be stored).But the problem is how you would store it to the database from that webpage.If you have a way for that you can try it too.

Comment: Any link can be requested.If you have code for insertion using javascript then you can request its link from Arduino and perform insertion.

Comment: Was these answers helpful.

Comment: Yup! Thank you sooooo much. I will try them :)